# Changing the values within a list so long as the values meets a certain condition

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I want to change the individual values within the list displayed below using a for loop. I tried the two ways that I instinctually thought to write the for loop, but neither work

I want a_list to become --> [2,3,3,4,4,5]

```
a_list = [1,2,2,3,4,5]


for values in a_list:
   if values < 4:
       values += 1


for values in a_list:
   if values < 4:
       a_list.index[values] += 1

print (a_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
new_list = [x+1 if x < 4 else x for x in a_list]
print(new_list)
```

If you want to use a normal for loop:

```
for i in range(len(a_list)):
   if a_list[i] < 4:
       a_list[i] += 1
```

Comment: Just like me! 
You were fist i think tou deserve the acceptance

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension:

```
m_list = [x+1 if x <4 else x for x in m_ list]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a copy of the value in the list.
a better approach is:

```
for index,values in enumerate(a_list):
   if values < 4:
       a_list[index]+= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
a_list = [1,2,2,3,4,5]


for i in range(len(a_list)):
   if a_list[i] < 4:
       a_list[i] = a_list[i]+1
a_list
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```